# Updating the matchData in a GKTurnBasedMatch without ending the turn

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, game-center, gamekit

It seems that GameKit only allows `GKTurnBasedMatch` to be updated once per time that `GKTurnBasedMatch` is loaded from the Game Center servers.  Is there an other way to update the `matchData` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method was added to GKTurnBasedMatch in iOS 6.0 and will do what you need:

```
- (void)saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:(NSData *)matchData
                   completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```

"Update the match data without advancing the game to another player"

Comment: Note that this triggers a push notification to opponents even though the current player's turn is not yet over!  See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760209/is-there-a-way-to-update-matchdata-in-a-gkturnbasedmatch-without-sending-out-yo/15825219#15825219).

Answer (score 4):

You can call `-

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch (void)loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *matchData, NSError *error))completionHandler];
```

as often as you like to get updated matchData. 
If you want to do incremental moves you also can do -

```
[GKTunrBasedMatch - (void)endTurnWithNextParticipant:(GKTurnBasedParticipant *)nextParticipant matchData:(NSData *)matchData completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler];
```

with your own participant as next participant. However, you have to loadMatchDataWithCompletionhandler:  once again after you submitted your partial move before you are allowed to submit the next move part.