# Is there a way to update matchData in a GKTurnBasedMatch without sending out "Your Turn" push notifications?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

If my understanding is correct, the only way to update the matchData property of a GKTurnBasedMatch mid-turn is [_currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipant:_currentParticipant matchData:matchData completionHandler:nil].

This works well if the Game Center player only has the game installed on one device because the notification is delivered to the device as a message to the app.  Thus, the notification can be hidden while the user is currently playing his turn.  However, if the user has the game installed on multiple devices, the other devices will get a "Your Turn" push notification.  This is confusing to the user, especially I update the matchData multiple times.

By the way, I understand that I may not be using the endTurnWithNextParticipant:matchData:completionHandler: function as it was intended (because I am not, in fact, ending the match... but merely updating the matchData).  However, there seems to be no alternative to update the match's state mid-turn.

Comment: Looks like your method of sending the turn was the right idea. This along with [the answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9267616/868193) gave me everything I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mid-turn saving has been added in iOS 6 with:

```
-[GKTurnBasedMatch saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:]
```

Source: [GKTurnBasedMatch Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, to address your original question, it appears that **saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData** *still* sends out push notifications to the other players, even though the current player's turn hasn't ended!

In my opinion, this seems like a GameKit design flaw- it seems inherently misleading to have a badge show up on an opponent's app icon when it isn't yet their turn.  What a bummer to open it and see that it's just a false alarm over and over!

If anyone has figured out a way to *suppress* these push notifications when calling **saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData**, I would love to hear how you did it.

**UPDATE**: I started a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847555/is-there-any-way-to-call-savecurrentturnwithmatchdata-without-sending-a-push-not) to address this issue.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't really be a reason to update the match data during the turn.  None of the other players can react until their turn, so the data only needs to be passed as play transitions from one player to another.

Comment: There's always a reason :) .  My reasons are: data persistance between devices AND preventing cheating such as force-quitting before the turn finished if you know you're going to lose.

Comment: Turn-based games often require extra data be sent while another player is taking their turn. For example, chat messages could be sent as match data and are very common in turn-based games utilizing parties or squad-based game play. Even head-to-head games like Words with Friends allow chat messages to be sent between turns.

Comment: On games with a randomly generated board, it's good to save the board to GameCenter before the player takes their turn, otherwise the player might be able to reload the app to change the board for the game.