# Is there any way to call saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData without sending a push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, gamekit

I have a Game Center game that allows players to make multiple moves per turn.  In iOS 6, Apple implemented a great feature in **saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData** that allows you to do just that- it saves the data to game center to prevent cheating by repeatedly redoing a move for instance, without advancing to the next player.

The problem is, I have discovered that this actually triggers the same Push Notification taht gets sent when the player *does* end their turn.  So other players in the game will see a badge on the app's icon and mistakenly think it's their turn when it isn't.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?  Any way to call **saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData** without sending a push notification?  If not, this seems like a design flaw that should probably be brought to Apple's attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to update matchData in a GKTurnBasedMatch without sending out "Your Turn" push notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760209/is-there-a-way-to-update-matchdata-in-a-gkturnbasedmatch-without-sending-out-yo)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this seems like a design flaw. I am also developing a turn-based game whereby a player can take several actions before passing control over to the next player. Meanwhile, I want other players to witness every action while they are looking at the game. If the other players are not running the app, I want them to receive a push notification only when the control is passed to another player.

Instead of using `saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:`, I use `endTurnWithNextParticipants:` but I specify the current player rather than the next. This seems to do the trick:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 86400; // seconds in a day
[currentMatch 
  endTurnWithNextParticipants:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:currentMatch.currentParticipant,nil] 
  turnTimeout:interval matchData:[self packMatchData]
  completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
       // handle error
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will give push notifications to any other device the current participant has the game installed on, as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760209/is-there-a-way-to-update-matchdata-in-a-gkturnbasedmatch-without-sending-out-yo)